# How Do I Use CSS to Set the Color of An ALink?

Tags: html, css

I’m trying to use CSS to set the color of an ALink but I’m obviously not succeeding.

Obviously I’m doing something wrong but after having screwed around with this seemingly trivial problem I still have no clue what I’m doing wrong.

Here’s the HTML /CSS …

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ALink Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
       a.Home:link{
        text-decoration:none;
        color:rgb (240, 180, 50);
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
     <a class="Home" href="http://www.subudnewyork.org/">Home</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

If anyone could explain to me what I’m doing wrong and, more importantly, how to fix it I would immensely appreciate it …

Answer (score 4):

Simply you have to remove space from `rgb (240, 180, 50)` as this `rgb(240, 180, 50)`.

See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dFYme/).

Comment: Hi "acdcjunior" … I tried your suggestion … It doesn't work … Do you have any other ideas that I might try ?

Comment: "Home" displays as a purple, with "rgb(240, 180, 80);" it should display with a tan color …

Comment: I should mention that I'm working on a Mac running OSX 10.6.8 & Safari  version 5.1.9 (6534.59.8)…

Comment: The purple color for "Home" appears to be the default color.I know this because if I delete the line of code "color:rgb(0, 180, 50);", I get the same color; i.e. : purple …

Comment: add !important at last i.e. rgb(240, 180, 50) !important;

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to add color via rgb to an element.

Either this:

```
color: rgb(240, 180, 50)
```

or this which adds opacity as well (but only works in browsers which support it)

```
color: rgba(240, 180, 50, 0.6)
```

Comment: Hi "Aditya Saxena" … If you look in the code I submitted along with my "Plea for Help' you will see that I've actually used "color:rgb(240, 180, 50)". It doesn't work … Do you have any other suggestions I might try ?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the space between the rgb and ( as suggested by @C-Link

Comment: @SimonWhelan hey buddy, did any of the solutions suggested here work for you ?